# Why do I get the warning: Must be one of: androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DEFAULT

Tags: android

I'm updating my code to work with API 32 and one of the things I have to do is call `setForegroundServiceBehavior`. When doing that I get this warning:

`Must be one of: androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DEFAULT, androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE, androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DEFERRED`

But if you look at the screenshot below, that is exactly what I am calling.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]